# Giving "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out" on one specific page

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I have created a web **scraper** which **scrapes** data from the page and store it in the .csv file. I have execute this program with the multiple pages but, there is a page when I execute my program with that link it gives an error of **"java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out"** on the line where I have created connection of jsoup library. I don't understand why it is giving error on that specific page. My code and log is mentioned below.
Note: I am using jsoup HTML parser, java 1.7, Netbeans.

```
public class ComOpen_end_fund {

    boolean writeCSVToConsole = true;
    boolean writeCSVToFile = true;
    boolean sortTheList = true;
    boolean writeToConsole;
    boolean writeToFile;
    public static Document doc = null;
    public static Elements tbodyElements = null;
    public static Elements elements = null;
    public static Elements tdElements = null;
    public static Elements trElement2 = null;
    public static String Dcomma = ",";
    public static String line = "";
    public static ArrayList<Elements> sampleList = new ArrayList<Elements>();

    public static void createConnection() throws IOException {
        System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "191.1.1.202");
        System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080");
        String tempUrl = "http://mufap.com.pk/nav-report.php?tab=01&fname=&amc=&cat=&strdate=&endate=&submitted=&mnt=&yrs=&s=";
        doc = Jsoup.connect(tempUrl).get(); //this is line number 42
    }

    public static void parsingHTML() throws Exception {
        for (Element table : doc.getElementsByTag("table")) {

            for (Element trElement : table.getElementsByTag("tr")) {
                trElement2 = trElement.getElementsByTag("tr");
                tdElements = trElement.getElementsByTag("td");
                File fold = new File("C:\\open-end-fund.csv");
                fold.delete();
                File fnew = new File("C:\\open-end-fund.csv");
                FileWriter sb = new FileWriter(fnew, true);
                if (trElement.hasClass("tab-data")) {
                    for (Iterator<Element> it = tdElements.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                        if (it.hasNext()) {
                            sb.append("\r\n");

                        }

                        for (Iterator<Element> it2 = trElement2.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                            Element tdElement2 = it.next();
                            final String content = tdElement2.text();
                            if (it2.hasNext()) {

                                sb.append(formatData(content));
                                sb.append("   ,   ");

                            }
                        }

                        System.out.println(sb.toString());
                        sb.flush();
                        sb.close();
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(sampleList.add(tdElements));

            }
        }
    }
    private static final SimpleDateFormat FORMATTER_MMM_d_yyyy = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy", Locale.US);
    private static final SimpleDateFormat FORMATTER_dd_MMM_yyyy = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-YYYY", Locale.US);

    public static String formatData(String text) {
        String tmp = null;

        try {
            Date d = FORMATTER_MMM_d_yyyy.parse(text);
            tmp = FORMATTER_dd_MMM_yyyy.format(d);
        } catch (ParseException pe) {
            tmp = text;
        }

        return tmp;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, Exception {
        createConnection(); //this is line number 100
        parsingHTML();

    }

}
```

and here is the log cat

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:704)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:647)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1536)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:516)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:493)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:205)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:194)
    at com.open_end_fund.ComOpen_end_fund.createConnection(ComOpen_end_fund.java:42)
    at com.open_end_fund.ComOpen_end_fund.main(ComOpen_end_fund.java:100)
C:\Users\talha\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 3 seconds)
```

When I am running this code on http://www.mufap.com.pk/nav_returns_performance.php?tab=01
this link it's working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to increase the timeout:

```
Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(30000).get();
```

This sets timeout to 30 seconds. The default is 3 seconds. If you set it to 0 it will behave as infinite timeout.

https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html#timeout-int-